# port number of server in log file name - log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Is there any way to configure log-file to be appended with the port number of application-server.

Example: if my spring boot web service is running on 5001 port, then the log file name must be appended with the port number.

Port number is not configured in application.yml file.

Also, I tried using lookup ${spring:server.port} from application.yml file, but it does not seem to work.

I found a post on stack overflow where it says,  log4j2 lookup works with Spring cloud config. I don't want to use cloud config.

Another post says to use higher version of log4j2 ie at least 2.13. But this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your port no in application.properties file and after that u can read that using Environment Object.

In application.properties :- server.port= 5001
In Log4j implementation class :-
@Autowired
Environment env;

String keyVal = env.getProperty("server.port");
And append this port to your Log4j file name.

Comment: What is this “Log4j implementation class”?

Comment: I am using automatic configuration. No explicit implementation class. All through log4j2.xml file.